# Good ways to "expand" a numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Are there good ways to "expand" a numpy ndarray? Say I have an ndarray like this:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

And I want each row to contains more elements by filling zeros:

```
[[1 2 0 0 0]
 [3 4 0 0 0]]
```

I know there must be some brute-force ways to do so (say construct a bigger array with zeros then copy elements from old smaller arrays), just wondering are there pythonic ways to do so. Tried `numpy.reshape` but didn't work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
np.reshape(a, (2, 5))
```

Numpy complains that: `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are the index tricks `r_` and `c_`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> z = np.zeros((2, 3), dtype=a.dtype)
>>> np.c_[a, z]
array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0, 0]])
```

If this is performance critical code, you might prefer to use the equivalent `np.concatenate` rather than the index tricks.

```
>>> np.concatenate((a,z), axis=1)
array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0, 0]])
```

There are also `np.resize` and `np.ndarray.resize`, but they have some limitations (due to the way numpy lays out data in memory) so read the docstring on those ones.  You will probably find that simply concatenating is better.

By the way, when I've needed to do this I usually just do it the basic way you've already mentioned (create an array of zeros and assign the smaller array inside it), I don't see anything wrong with that!

Answer (score 83):

You can use [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,0),(0,3)), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Here `np.pad` says, "Take the array `a` and add 0 rows above it, 0 rows below it, 0 columns to the left of it, and 3 columns to the right of it. Fill these columns with a `constant` specified by `constant_values`".

Comment: As a personal experience, I was using np.pad to dynamically expand the size of an array and notice a very poor time performance. After I changed to np.concatenate the run time was reduce ~x10 times.

Answer (score 19):

Just to be clear: there's no "good" way to extend a NumPy array, as NumPy arrays are **not** expandable. Once the array is defined, the space it occupies in memory, a combination of the number of its elements and the size of each element, is fixed and cannot be changed. The only thing you can do is to create a new array and replace some of its elements by the elements of the original array.

A lot of functions are available for convenience (the [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) function and its `np.*stack` shortcuts, the [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html), the indexes routines [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and `np.c_`...), but there are just that: convenience functions. Some of them are optimized at the C level (the `np.concatenate` and others, I think), some are not.

Note that there's nothing at all with your initial suggestion of creating a large array 'by hand' (possibly filled with zeros) and filling it yourself with your initial array. It might be more readable that more complicated solutions.

Comment: +1 though there is `np.ndarray.resize`, which changes size of an array in place.  it does reallocate space for data _if necessary_

Comment: ...provided the array is (i) contiguous and (ii) not a reference to another array. And the result has always to be triple-checked anyway, so I wonder whether it's really worth the hassle.

Comment: +1 to the fixed size remark on Numpy arrays. If you have to do this a lot, it is better to use lists and cast them to arrays at the end.

Answer (score 12):

### A simple way:

```
# what you want to expand
x = np.ones((3, 3))

# expand to what shape 
target = np.zeros((6, 6))

# do expand
target[:x.shape[0], :x.shape[1]] = x

# print target
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

### Functional way:

borrow from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35751427/1637673, with a little modification.

```
def pad(array, reference_shape, offsets=None):
    """
    array: Array to be padded
    reference_shape: tuple of size of narray to create
    offsets: list of offsets (number of elements must be equal to the dimension of the array)
    will throw a ValueError if offsets is too big and the reference_shape cannot handle the offsets
    """

    if not offsets:
        offsets = np.zeros(array.ndim, dtype=np.int32)

    # Create an array of zeros with the reference shape
    result = np.zeros(reference_shape, dtype=np.float32)
    # Create a list of slices from offset to offset + shape in each dimension
    insertHere = [slice(offsets[dim], offsets[dim] + array.shape[dim]) for dim in range(array.ndim)]
    # Insert the array in the result at the specified offsets
    result[insertHere] = array
    return result
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use `np.column_stack` or `append`

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([ [1,2] , [3,4] ])

p = np.column_stack( [ p , [ 0 , 0 ],[0,0] ] )

p
Out[277]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 0, 0]])
```

Append seems to be faster though:

```
timeit np.column_stack( [ p , [ 0 , 0 ],[0,0] ] )
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.8 us per loop

timeit np.append(p, [[0,0],[0,0]],1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 48 us per loop
```

And a comparison with `np.c_` and `np.hstack` [append still seems to be the fastest]:

```
In [295]: z=np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=a.dtype)

In [296]: timeit np.c_[a, z]
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.2 us per loop

In [297]: timeit np.append(p, z,1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 us per loop

In [305]: timeit np.hstack((p,z))
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.8 us per loop
```

and `np.concatenate` [that is a even a bit faster than `append`]:

```
In [307]: timeit np.concatenate((p, z), axis=1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.6 us per loop
```

Comment: strange.  you might find `np.concatenate((a, z), axis=1)` to be faster than append

Comment: yep, this is because append does some extra logic (which is not actually needed here) before simply calling concatenate.

Answer (score 6):

there are also similar methods like np.vstack, np.hstack, np.dstack. I like these over np.concatente as it makes it clear what dimension is being "expanded".

```
temp = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
np.hstack((temp, np.zeros((2,3))))
```

it's easy to remember becase numpy's first axis is vertical so vstack expands the first axis and 2nd axis is horizontal so hstack.