# ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: [['1', '2', '3'], ['1']] - got shape [2], but wanted [2, 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

using python 3.x tensorflow version 1.8.0

code1:

```
a2 = [['1', '2'], ['1', '2']]
print(tf.shape(a2))
```

cod2:

```
a2 = [['1', '2', '3'], ['1']] 
print(tf.shape(a2))
```

cod1 is success but code2 error:

```
ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: [['1', '2', '3'], ['1']] - got shape [2], but wanted [2, 3].
```

tensorflow var has balance?
why code2 is error?

Comment: What kind of question is "tensorflow var has balance?"

Comment: Furthermore, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a list of lists with different sizes as a tensor.

To solve it, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619143/convert-python-sequence-to-numpy-array-filling-missing-values) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580716/how-to-input-a-list-of-lists-with-different-sizes-in-tf-data-dataset)