# how to convert padarray post to python pad function

Tags: python, matlab, pad

im having a problem to convert post in matlab padarray to pad function in python,
i want to do the same in python pad function  :

```
padded=np.pad(MAT,(1,1),'post');
```

this is not working because there is no post function in python

this is an example in matlab (i want to do the same in python pad function):

[image]

it will really help me , thank you

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751306/python-how-to-pad-numpy-array-with-zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=np.array([[1,3,4]])
b=np.pad(a,((0,1),(0,0)),'constant')
```

Notice that a should be a two dimensional array.
If this is confusing, read the documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html

Comment: ok great , i have just fixed it to : b=np.pad(a,((0,1),(0,1)),'constant') and its working well thank you !