# How can I convert an array containing arrays of different lengths into a tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

How can I convert an array containing arrays of different lengths into a pytorch tensor? e.g.

```
devX = array([ 
              array([1,2,3,4]),
              array([1,2,3])
              array([1,2,3,4,5]) 
            ])
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35751427/6253220) might help you

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: Is it possible to do so without padding? Result should be the same as above but in a tensor

Comment: A tensor is a multi-dimensional matrix containing elements of a single data type, so I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Except padding you can use `PackedSequence` but would have to sort them beforehand (and keep unsorting array), not sure what's your use case though. Otherwise padding is the only way to go

Comment: Rows must have the same sizes. `[torch.tensor(a) for a in devX]` you can use list of tensors, if its good for you