# numpy multiply the shape of an array to make a larger array

Tags: numpy, python-3.6

I assume this is very easy, but I'm not seeing it.

I have a numpy array that is (800, 600) and I want to make a new array that is 3x the original size in both directions.  When I multiply the shape I get a strange result.  I know I can do this with the array notation, but is there a way to do it without that?

```
>>> img.shape
(800, 600)
>>> img.shape * 3
(800, 600, 800, 600, 800, 600)
>>> (img.shape[0] * 3, img.shape[1] * 3)
(2400, 1800)
>>>
```

I have an original image X, and want to surround it with whitespace the size of the image in all directions.  So:

```
x

www
wxw
www
```

I was thinking of using `np.ones((new 3x size))` and then copying the image in with the offset width*height of the original image.

Comment: Multiplying the `.shape` attribute and actually increasing the size of the array are two very different things.

Comment: `shape` is a tuple.  `tuple * n` is a replication operation.

Comment: What are the contents of your increased array?

Comment: It would be best if you could produce a 3x3 array and explain how you would want it to look as a 6x6 (or 9x9, whichever).

Comment: If  you  make a new larger array you will have a lot of new, undefined elements.  What values should they have?

Comment: I was going to use np.ones() with the resulting new size.

Comment: Maybe `tuple(map(lambda x: 3*x, img.shape))` would be a bit more elegant

Comment: Or `tuple(i*3 for i in img.shape)`

Comment: this should help find the answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35751427

Comment: So basically you calculate the new shape (ordinary math on a tuple), create the properly filled array of that size, and then copy the original values into the desired subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to broadcast the multiplication you can the the python's tuple "shape" into a numpy array and then perform the calculation, i.e.:

```
expanded_shape = np.array(img.shape)*3
```

For the padding itself by the way you wanted to do it, you can do something like this:

```
expanded_img = np.ones(expanded_shape)
expanded_img[img.shape[0]:img.shape[0]*2, img.shape[1]:img.shape[1]*2] = img
```

However you can use `np.pad` function as well. It is well [documented](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) (look at the last example there, I think it is exactly what you need).