# I wanted to implement Convolutional Neural Network without builtin functions.So How can I pad my image matrix with zeros around the matrix

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've used many builtin methods in python opencv.But I wanted to implement that without those builtin functions.So for that I need to add zeros around the image.So I can iterate the Kernel Matrix to find edge values too..
[image]

I wanna implement the same like the image that I've attached.
I wanted to do that in Python.Please do Help me.
Thanks

Comment: All you have to do is pad your numpy array with zeros. Check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751306/python-how-to-pad-numpy-array-with-zeros

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image into a numpy array. 
Then refer the following link to pad it with zeros - [python how to pad numpy array with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751306/python-how-to-pad-numpy-array-with-zeros)