# How can I right pad a numpy array with zeroes?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` array with shape `(1, 79, 161)`. I need to make the shape `(1, 100, 161)` by padding the center axis with zeroes to the right.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you seen [`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)?

Comment: I have - but am unsure how to use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python how to pad numpy array with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751306/python-how-to-pad-numpy-array-with-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic approach using `np.pad`. The trick is to get the `pad_width` argument right. In your original question, the correct `pad_width` would be `[(0, 0), (0, 21), (0, 0)]`. Each pair of numbers is the padding before the axis and then after the axis. You want to right pad the second dimension, so the pair should be `(0, 21)`. The methods below calculate the correct pad width argument based on shape of the original array and the desired array shape.

```
import numpy as np

orig_shape = (1, 79, 161)
new_shape = (1, 100, 161)

pad_width = [(0, j - i) for i, j in zip(orig_shape, new_shape)]
# pad_width = [(0, 0), (0, 21), (0, 0)]
orig_array = np.random.rand(*orig_shape)
padded = np.pad(orig_array, pad_width)
```

---

Another option: you can create a new numpy array of zeros, and then fill it in with your existing values.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((1, 100, 161))
x[:, :79, :] = OLD_ARRAY
```

Comment: Can this be made generic?

Comment: You will have to be more specific. What are the requirements?

Comment: In this case, it's `79`. But for other instances, it might be a different number

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
>>> x = np.ones((1,79,161))
>>> x
array([[[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]]])
>>> y = np.pad(x, ((0,0), (0,1), (0, 0)))
>>> y
array([[[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]])
>>> y.shape
(1, 80, 161)
>>> z = np.pad(x, ((0,0), (0,21), (0, 0)))
>>> z.shape
(1, 100, 161)
```

The tuples signify `padding_width` before and after for each dimension.