# Complete numpy array of arrays to matrix

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

how can complete this ndarray (matrix):

```
np.array([[2,2], [2]])
```

to be a matrix, with zeroes in the missing values:

```
np.array([[2,2], [2,0]])
```

thanks.

Comment: Check out numpy.pad() function. It seems like a solution for you. Also take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751306/python-how-to-pad-numpy-array-with-zeros

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python how to pad numpy array with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751306/python-how-to-pad-numpy-array-with-zeros)

Comment: This is not a padding problem @izhang05 padding works well with homogeneous arrays, and serves another purpose

Comment: padding doesn't work,
the problem is that it also create a np array of lists.