# Fit curve to data, get analytical form, & check when curve crosses threshold

Tags: python, curve-fitting, spline

I have 40 points for each curve and I would like to smooth the function and estimate when the curve crosses a threshold on the y axis.
Is there a fitting function that I can easily apply this to, I can use interpolate to plot the new function but I can't figure out how to request the x value for which y = threshold.

Unfortunately the curves don't all have the same shape so I can't use scipy.optimize.curve_fit.

Thanks!

Update: Adding two curves:

Curve 1

```
[942.153,353.081,53.088,125.110,140.851,188.170,70.536,-122.473,-369.061,-407.945,88.734,484.334,267.762,65.831,74.010,-55.781,-260.024,-466.830,-524.511,-76.833,-36.779,-117.366,218.578,175.662,185.653,299.285,215.276,546.048,1210.132,3087.326,7052.849,13867.824,27156.939,51379.664,91908.266,148874.563,215825.031,290073.219,369567.781,437031.688]
```

Curve 2

```
[-39034.039,-34637.941,-24945.094,-16697.996,-9247.398,-2002.051,3409.047,3658.145,7542.242,11781.340,11227.688,10089.035,9155.883,8413.980,5289.578,3150.676,4590.023,6342.871,3294.719,580.567,-938.586,-3919.738,-5580.390,-3141.793,-2785.945,-2683.597,-4287.750,-4947.902,-7347.554,-8919.457,-6403.359,-6722.011,-8181.414,-6807.566,-7603.218,-6298.371,-6909.523,-5878.675,-5193.578,-7193.980]
```

x values are

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]
```

Comment: The good thing about `scipy.optimize.cuve_fit` is that it doesn't require all curves to have the same shape. Would you be able to provide us some example data to work with?

Comment: I've added these

Comment: You can use a cubic spline fit, which would give you the intersections very nicely

Comment: Maybe run a low pass filter over it first

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did try to use from 
scipy import interpolate
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic'), but I don't know how to get the intersections from the output f, any help appreciated.

Comment: Cubics have closed form roots

Comment: Yes, but I don't know where to get the expression for the cubic fit.

Comment: Is there a special reason for using cubic, instead of Legendre?

Comment: No, Legendre works well too, I just prefer a method that outputs an analytical function rather than check with an array to see when the function crosses the threshold.

Comment: Alright! You can get analytical form of the Legendre fit as well.

Comment: Oh perfect, how?

Comment: Added a way to obtain analytical form, let me know if it doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fitting a smooth curve, you can fit [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) using [numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.html)'s [fit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.fit) method.

---

```
# import packages we need later
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

---

### Fitting Legendre Polynomials

Preparing data [as numpy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html):

```
curve1 = \
np.asarray([942.153,353.081,53.088,125.110,140.851,188.170,70.536,-122.473,-369.061,-407.945,88.734,484.334,267.762,65.831,74.010,-55.781,-260.024,-466.830,-524.511,-76.833,-36.779,-117.366,218.578,175.662,185.653,299.285,215.276,546.048,1210.132,3087.326,7052.849,13867.824,27156.939,51379.664,91908.266,148874.563,215825.031,290073.219,369567.781,437031.688])
curve2 = \
np.asarray([-39034.039,-34637.941,-24945.094,-16697.996,-9247.398,-2002.051,3409.047,3658.145,7542.242,11781.340,11227.688,10089.035,9155.883,8413.980,5289.578,3150.676,4590.023,6342.871,3294.719,580.567,-938.586,-3919.738,-5580.390,-3141.793,-2785.945,-2683.597,-4287.750,-4947.902,-7347.554,-8919.457,-6403.359,-6722.011,-8181.414,-6807.566,-7603.218,-6298.371,-6909.523,-5878.675,-5193.578,-7193.980])
xvals = \
np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40])
```

Lets fit the Legendre polynomials, `degree` being the highest degree polynomial used, [the first few is here for example](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/legend.html).

```
degree=10
legendrefit_curve1 = np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.fit(xvals, curve1, deg=degree)
legendrefit_curve2 = np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.fit(xvals, curve2, deg=degree)
```

Calculate these fitted curves at evenly spaced points using the [linspace method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.linspace.html#numpy.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.linspace). `n` is the number of point pairs we want to have.

```
n=100
fitted_vals_curve1 = legendrefit_curve1.linspace(n=n)
fitted_vals_curve2 = legendrefit_curve2.linspace(n=n)
```

Let's plot the result, along with a `threshold` (using [axvline](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html)):

```
plt.scatter(xvals, curve1)
plt.scatter(xvals, curve2)

plt.plot(fitted_vals_curve1[0],fitted_vals_curve1[1],c='r')
plt.plot(fitted_vals_curve2[0],fitted_vals_curve2[1],c='k')

threshold=100000
plt.axhline(y=threshold)
```

[image]

The curves fit beautifully.

---

### When is the threshold crossed?

To check where the `threshold` is crossed in each series, you can do:

```
for x, y in zip(fitted_vals_curve1[0], fitted_vals_curve1[1]):
    if y > threshold:
        xcross_curve1 = x
        break

for x, y in zip(fitted_vals_curve2[0], fitted_vals_curve2[1]):
    if y > threshold:
        xcross_curve2 = x
        break
```

`xcross_curve1` and `xcross_curve2` will hold the `x` value where `curve1` and `curve2` crossed the `threshold` if they did cross the `threshold`; if they did not, they will be undefined.

Let's plot them to check if it works ([link to axhline docs](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html)):

```
plt.scatter(xvals, curve1)
plt.scatter(xvals, curve2)

plt.plot(fitted_vals_curve1[0],fitted_vals_curve1[1],c='r')
plt.plot(fitted_vals_curve2[0],fitted_vals_curve2[1],c='k')

plt.axhline(y=threshold)

try: plt.axvline(x=xcross_curve1)
except NameError: print('curve1 is not passing the threshold',c='b')

try: plt.axvline(x=xcross_curve2)
except NameError: print('curve2 is not passing the threshold')
```

As expected, we get this plot:

[image]

(and a text output: `curve2 is not passing the threshold`.)

If you would like to increase accuracy of `xcross_curve1` or `xcross_curve2`, you can increase `degree` and `n` defined above.

---

### From Legendre to Polynomial form

We have fitted a curve, which roughly has the form:

[image]
where `P_n` is the `n`th Legendre polynomial, `s(x)` is some function which transforms `x` to the range `P_n` expects (some math stuff which we don't need to know now).

We want our fitted line in the form:

[image]

We'll use `legendre()` of [scipy.special](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.legendre.html):

```
from scipy.special import legendre
```

We'll also use use `np.pad` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), [good SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115998/8565438)).

```
legendredict={}
for icoef, coef in enumerate(legendrefit_curve1.coef):
    legendredict[icoef]=coef*np.pad(legendre(icoef).coef,(10-icoef,0),mode='constant')
```

`legendredict` will hold `keys` from `0` to `10`, and each value in the `dict` will be a list of `float`s. The `key` is refering to the degree of the Polynomial, and the list of `float`s are expressing what are the coefficients of `x**n` values within that constituent polynomial of our fit, in a backwards order.

For example:

`P_4` is:

[image]

`legendredict[4]` is:

```
isarray([ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  3.29634565e+05,  3.65967884e-11,
       -2.82543913e+05,  1.82983942e-11,  2.82543913e+04])
```

Meaning that in the *sum* of `P_n`s (`f(x)`, above), we have `q_4` lot of `P_4`, which is equivalent to having `2.82543913e+04` of `1`s, `1.82983942e-11` of `x`, `-2.82543913e+05` of `x^2`, etc, *only from the `P_4` component*.

So if we want to know how much `1`s, `x`s, `x^2`s, etc we need to form the polynomial sum, we need to add the need for `1`s, `x`s, `x^2`s, etcs from all the different `P_n`s. This is what we do:

```
polycoeffs = np.sum(np.stack(list(legendredict.values())),axis=0)
```

Then let's form a polynomial sum:

```
for icoef, coef in enumerate(reversed(polycoeffs)):
    print(str(coef)+'*s(x)**'+str(icoef),end='\n +')
```

Giving the output:

```
-874.1456709637822*s(x)**0
 +2893.7228005540596*s(x)**1
 +50415.38472217957*s(x)**2
 +-6979.322584205707*s(x)**3
 +-453363.49985790614*s(x)**4
 +-250464.7549807652*s(x)**5
 +1250129.5521521813*s(x)**6
 +1267709.5031024509*s(x)**7
 +-493280.0177807359*s(x)**8
 +-795684.224334346*s(x)**9
 +-134370.1696946264*s(x)**10
 +
```

(We are going to ignore the last `+` sign, formatting is not the main point here.)

We need to calculate `s(x)` as well. If we are working in a Jupyter Notebook / [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#recent=true), only executing a cell with `legendrefit_curve1` returns:

[image]

From where we can clearly see that `s(x)` is `-1.0512820512820513+0.05128205128205128x`. If we want to do it in a more programmatic way:

`2/(legendrefit_curve1.domain[1]-legendrefit_curve1.domain[0])` is `0.05128205128205128` &
`-1-2/(legendrefit_curve1.domain[1]-legendrefit_curve1.domain[0])` is just `-1.0512820512820513`

Which is true for some mathamatical reasons not much relevant here ([related Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63120942/how-do-i-get-the-function-which-transforms-an-input-to-be-the-argument-of-a-lege)).

So we can define:

```
def s(input):
    a=-1-2/(legendrefit_curve1.domain[1]-legendrefit_curve1.domain[0])
    b=2/(legendrefit_curve1.domain[1]-legendrefit_curve1.domain[0])
    return a+b*input
```

Also, lets define, based on the above obtained sum of polynomials of `s(x)`:

```
def polyval(x):
    return -874.1456709637822*s(x)**0+2893.7228005540596*s(x)**1+50415.38472217957*s(x)**2+-6979.322584205707*s(x)**3+-453363.49985790614*s(x)**4+-250464.7549807652*s(x)**5+1250129.5521521813*s(x)**6+1267709.5031024509*s(x)**7+-493280.0177807359*s(x)**8+-795684.224334346*s(x)**9+-134370.1696946264*s(x)**10
```

In a more programmatic way:

```
def polyval(x):
    return sum([coef*s(x)**icoef for icoef, coef in enumerate(reversed(polycoeffs))])
```

Check that our polynomial indeed fits:

```
plt.scatter(fitted_vals_curve1[0],fitted_vals_curve1[1],c='r')
plt.plot(fitted_vals_curve1[0],[polyval(val) for val in fitted_vals_curve1[0]])
```

It does:

[image]

So let's print out our pure polynomial sum, with `s(x)` being replaced by an explicit function:

```
for icoef, coef in enumerate(reversed(polycoeffs)):
    print(str(coef)+'*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**'+str(icoef),end='\n +')
```

Giving the output:

```
-874.1456709637822*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**0
 +2893.7228005540596*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**1
 +50415.38472217957*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**2
 +-6979.322584205707*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**3
 +-453363.49985790614*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**4
 +-250464.7549807652*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**5
 +1250129.5521521813*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**6
 +1267709.5031024509*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**7
 +-493280.0177807359*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**8
 +-795684.224334346*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**9
 +-134370.1696946264*(-1.0512820512820513+0512820512820513*x)**10
 +
```

Which can be simplified, as desired. *(Ignore the last `+` sign.)*

*If want a higher (lower) degree polynomial fit, just fit higher (lower) degrees of Legendre polynomials.*

Comment: Hope this helps, let me know if there are issues.