# How do I get the function which transforms an input to be the argument of a Legendre polynomial when using numpy.polynomial.legendre?

Tags: python, numpy, math, curve-fitting

```
# import packages we need later
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

---

### What I am doing

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63037985/8565438)  & [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63039152/8565438), I am fitting a series of [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) to a [time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series#:%7E:text=A%20time%20series%20is%20a,sequence%20of%20discrete%2Dtime%20data.):

```
curve1 = \
np.asarray([942.153,353.081,53.088,125.110,140.851,188.170,70.536,-122.473,-369.061,-407.945,88.734,484.334,267.762,65.831,74.010,-55.781,-260.024,-466.830,-524.511,-76.833,-36.779,-117.366,218.578,175.662,185.653,299.285,215.276,546.048,1210.132,3087.326,7052.849,13867.824,27156.939,51379.664,91908.266,148874.563,215825.031,290073.219,369567.781,437031.688])
```

The time values:

```
tvals = \
np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40])
```

Using a numpy's function:

```
degree=10
legendrefit_curve1 = np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre.fit(tvals, curve1, deg=degree)
```

The fit seems pretty good:

```
# generate points of fitted curve
n=100
fitted_vals_curve1 = legendrefit_curve1.linspace(n=n)

# plot data and fitted curve
plt.scatter(tvals, curve1)
plt.plot(fitted_vals_curve1[0],fitted_vals_curve1[1],c='r')
```

[image]

---

### What's the question

`print(legendrefit_curve1)` returns:

```
leg([ 36823.85778316  96929.13731379 123557.55165344 112110.13559758
  75345.0434688   32377.19460001   -182.38440131 -15562.47475287
 -16142.22533582  -8379.06875482   -744.73929814])
```

However, I am using a Jupyter notebook, so if I just write `legendrefit_curve1`, without [`print()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp#:%7E:text=The%20print()%20function%20prints,before%20written%20to%20the%20screen.), I get an output:

[image]

*(What difference [`print()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp#:%7E:text=The%20print()%20function%20prints,before%20written%20to%20the%20screen.) makes to Jupyter's output is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882061/print-or-not-to-print-a-tensorflow-python-framework-ops-eagertensor-differ).)*

Clearly, `print(legendrefit_curve1)` only gave the coefficients of each Legendre polynomial (same with `legendrefit_curve1.coef`).

**How do I get the values which transform x to be the argument of each Legendre polynomial?**

ie how to obtain the values from the expression: `-1.0512820512820513+0.05128205128205128x`: `-1.0512820512820513` and `0.05128205128205128` (without just copying them manually)?

---

### What didn't work

Relying on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637293/iterate-over-object-attributes-in-python) I run:

```
for attr in dir(legendrefit_curve1):
    print('###'+attr+'###')
    print(getattr(legendrefit_curve1, attr))
```

This had a long text output, but I did not find `-1.05` in it (`ctrl-f`), so that suggest that the `-1.0512820512820513` value did not get returned, so this method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at those numbers I realized I can construct them from math.

`1/(len(curve1)-1)*2`, ie `1/39*2` returns: `0.05128205128205128`

`1+1/(len(curve1)-1)*2` ie `1+1/39*2` returns: `1.05

*Which are the numbers we were looking for.*

---

I still don't know how it is displayed when executing `legendrefit_curve1` in a Jupyter Notebook cell, but that is less of the point.

---

*I don't know why the formula above works, it'll probably be a question on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).*