# How can I add more neurons / filters to a neural network model after training?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm interested in training both a CNN model and a simple linear feed forward model in PyTorch, and after training to add more filters -- to the CNN layers, & neurons -- to the linear model layers and the outputs (e.g. from binary classification to multiclass classification) of both. By adding them I specifically mean to keep the weights that were trained constant, and to add random initialized weights to the new, incoming weights.

There's an example of a CNN model [here](https://nextjournal.com/gkoehler/pytorch-mnist), and an example of a simple linear feed forward model [here](https://medium.com/biaslyai/pytorch-introduction-to-neural-network-feedforward-neural-network-model-e7231cff47cb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was a bit tricky and requires `slice` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) for more info about `slice`, but it should be intuitive). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35751427/10886420) for slice trick. Please see comments for explanation:

```
import torch
    
def expand(
    original: torch.nn.Module,
    *args,
    **kwargs
    # Add other arguments if needed, like different stride
    # They won't change weights shape, but may change behaviour
):
    new = type(original)(*args, **kwargs)

    new_weight_shape = torch.tensor(new.weight.shape)
    new_bias_shape = torch.tensor(new.bias.shape)

    original_weight_shape = torch.tensor(original.weight.shape)
    original_bias_shape = torch.tensor(original.bias.shape)
    # I assume bias and weight exist, if not, do some checks
    # Also quick check, that new layer is "larger" than original
    assert torch.all(new_weight_shape >= original_weight_shape)
    assert new_bias_shape >= original_bias_shape

    # All the weights will be inputted from top to bottom, bias 1D assumed
    new.bias.data[:original_bias_shape] = original.bias.data

    # Create slices 0:n for each dimension
    slicer = tuple([slice(0, dim) for dim in original_weight_shape])
    # And input the data
    new.weight.data[slicer] = original.weight.data

    return new


layer = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)

new = expand(layer, in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
```

This should work for any layer (which has `weight` and `bias`, adjust if needed). Using this approach you can recreate your neural network or use PyTorch's `apply` (docs [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.apply))

Also remember, that you have to explicitly pass creational `*args` and `**kwargs` for "new layer" which will have trained connections inputted.

Comment: Looks great. I'm still going over the code and trying it out. Quick question, shouldn't the `in_channels` be the same? as the input itself doesn't change

Comment: It can be the same, it’s up to you. It cannot be smaller than original though, only restriction.

Comment: Okay perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. You also made it really simple to understand which I really appreciate! Tested it with both CNN and basic Linear model and it works perfectly