# Adding a numpy array to another which has different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, average

I have an empty numpy array (let's call it `a`), which is for example `(1200, 1000)` in size.

There are several numpy arrays that I want to get sum of them and save them in the array `a`.

The size of these arrays (`b_i`) are like `(1200, y)`, and `y` is `max=1000`.

Simply writing a code such as:

```
a = a + b_i
```

didn't work because of second dimension mismatch.

How can I solve that?

Comment: You can't sum up arrays with mismatching dimensions. Are you looking at concatenating them maybe?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Did you get an error? If so what was the error?

Comment: Please show a small example of what inputs might look like, and what output you expect. Your account is over 9 years old and you have multiple questions asked this year, so you should know well how this works by now, but: When something "didn't work", please explain exactly what that entails. If the output was wrong, show the wrong output, and explain how it is different from the expected output. If there was an error message, show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) error message, formatted like code.

Comment: What is it supposed to do with the dimensions don't match?  Don't assume that `numpy` operates with the same logic or intuition that you have.

Comment: have you tried to pad numpy array with zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to concatinate arrays:

```
a = np.ones((1200,1000))
b = np.ones((1200, 500))
c = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
c.shape # == (1200, 1500)
```

If you want elementwise addition, then reshape `b` to have the same dimentions as `a`

```
a = np.ones((1200,1000))
b = np.ones((1200, 500))
b_pad = np.zeros(a.shape)
b_pad[:b.shape[0],:b.shape[1]] = b
a + b_pad
```

```
array([[2., 2., 2., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       ...,
       [2., 2., 2., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., ..., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

If you want a reusable function for this, then have a look at this question

- [python how to pad numpy array with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751306/python-how-to-pad-numpy-array-with-zeros)

Comment: Numpy has a [pad function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html): `a + np.pad(b, a.shape[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have with this is to start taking a sub-array of `a` with dimensions matching the `b_i` array and adding it that way. So something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((12, 10))
b_1 = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(12, 5))
b_2 = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(12, 7))
b_3 = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(12, 9))
arrs = [b_1, b_2, b_3]

for arr in arrs:
    a[:, :arr.shape[1]] += arr
```

Or alternatively, as @BlackRaven had suggested you could instead pad the `b_i` with zeros to get it to the same shape as `a`.