# Can I use np.resize to pad an array with np.nan

Tags: python, numpy

Let

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a

array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Then use `resize`

```
b = np.resize(a, (3, 3))
b

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 1]])
```

`b` now has all of the information from `a` if in a wonky order. Is there a way to leverage this to create what looks like a in the top left but now has one new column and one new row of np.nan?

```
c = np.empty(b.shape)
c.fill(np.nan)
c[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]] = a
c

array([[  1.,   2.,  nan],
       [  3.,   4.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

---

Obviously the above code accomplishes the same thing.  I just can't help but think that `resize` can be used in some way to accomplish this more efficiently.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12668027/674039

Comment: That `wonky order` is just repeated copies of the data (as flattened).  `c.resize` pads with 0s, but again in the flattened order.  Neither form of `resize` gets used much.

Comment: Your last code is not inefficient.  It may be a bit wordy, but it is more efficient than `pad`, which has to be much more general purposed.  Look at the code for `np.resize`, `np.full` and `np.pad` - those are all written in Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe look at [`pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,1),(0,1)), 'constant', constant_values=np.nan)
array([[  1.,   2.,  nan],
       [  3.,   4.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

Note that `nan` is actually a float, so take care if trying to do this with integer dtypes.  You might prefer to use masked arrays.

Comment: in fact, I had to use `np.pad(a.astype(float)...`

Comment: Confirmed that it doesn't work with int data types (you get a large negative int value instead), I'm glad you mentioned the need for float.