# Reshaping python array for unknown rows using -1 & filling remaining spaces with None

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with unknown length (for example lets use 11). so the array is

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

I want to reshape that array so he will have 5 columns and as much rows as needed. I know I can use `reshape(-1,5)`  that way it creates the rows based on the array length.

But it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 11 into shape (5)
```

Any idea how do I do that? the desired result is:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,7,8,9,10],
[11,None,None,None,None]]
```

The code that I ran and got this error is:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])    
print(np.reshape(a, (-1,5)))
```

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253044/can-i-use-np-resize-to-pad-an-array-with-np-nan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without numpy.

```
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
n = 5
reshaped = [ar[i: i + n] + [None] * (i + n - len(ar)) for i in range(0, len(ar), n)]
```

You can also use trick with iterator (chunks will be in tuples):

```
reshaped = list(zip(*[iter(ar + [None] * (n - len(ar) % n))] * n))
```

You can apply [`zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from itertools to not add `None` values by yourself:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
reshaped = list(zip_longest(*[iter(ar)] * n))
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way? maybe one numpy function or withput loops?

Comment: @orr. what do you mean under "efficient"? You can't split list to chunks without loops. I'm not specialist in numpy, so I don't know it's methods.

Comment: by efficient I mean built-in numpy functions so that will make faster runtime. your answer is great, but I am curious to knoe whether there is faster way.

Comment: @orr, if tests from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555709/10824407) answer is correct, numpy 3 times slower then list comprehension.

Comment: haha thats funny, I thought numpy should be more faster. I guess I was wrong, thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [135]: res = np.empty((3,5), object)                                                                      
In [136]: res                                                                                                
Out[136]: 
array([[None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
In [137]: res.flat[:11] = np.arange(1,12)                                                                    
In [138]: res                                                                                                
Out[138]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       [11, None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: the thing is I dont know the row number, so I dont know the size of the empty None array I need. I only know the columns

Comment: But you can calculate the row number.  The next multiple of 5 up from 11 is 15.  15/5 gives me 3.